# The bootstrap navbar can't show appropriately on iOS system

Tags: html, css, ios, bootstrap-4, navbar

I use bootstrap to build a navbar of my website. And I open the website on computer and cellphone to try it. It works well on Samsung cellphone and also on computer. But when I open it on iPhone 8 and 6.
The navbar seems like covered by something . And it can't show well.

I think it might be something wrong about z-index or overflow . I try transform z index and let overflow be auto or visible . But they all can't work.

**Here is my boilerplate**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YelpCamp</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-DhY6onE6f3zzKbjUPRc2hOzGAdEf4/Dz+WJwBvEYL/lkkIsI3ihufq9hk9K4lVoK" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
<%- include('../partials/navbar')%>
<main class="container mt-5">
    <%- include('../partials/flash.ejs') %>
    <%- body %>
</main>
<%- include('../partials/footer')%>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.min.js">/script>
<script src="/javascript/validateForm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is my navbar**

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YelpCamp</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Campgrounds</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds/new">New Campground</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <% if(!currentUser) {%>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
            <% } else {%>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and CSS**

```
nav{
-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);
-moz-transform:translateZ(1px);
-o-transform:translateZ(1px);
transform:translateZ(1px);
overflow: visible;
}
.container-fluid{
transform:translateZ(1px);
overflow: visible;
}
```

And here is my whole app on GitHub
https://github.com/goodday2871/newyelpcamp

I deploy it on Heroku server. Here is the link
https://lit-shore-17312.herokuapp.com/

Thanks for any help and advice!!

---

https://upload.cc/i1/2020/11/22/xIt5LH.jpeg
Hi here is the image for my iPhone safari when I open my website.

Comment: Hi, I’ve tried the heroku version on IOS14 on an iPad and the navbar seems to work. Could you explain a bit more what doesn’t show well means?

Comment: Hi OrAssayag , Thanks for your test and feedback. I post the image for I see in my iphone8. I think maybe the problem is from bootstrap lib . I'll try to change the version of bootstrap. If it works, I'll post it!